# How to make a POST with XML body/content-type header using request promise native in Node?

Tags: node.js, xml, xml-parsing, request, request-promise

I need to make an XML POST (I know don't ask it's government...) and I can't get it to work with node request promise native.

I have tried turning my string of XML into a buffer, String(), .toString etc. The POST works if I turn json:true so I don't think it's a networking issue ( when passed a xml string with json true it sends a json like { 'variablename': 'stringed XML that I want to send as the body' } )

Here is what I'm working with. I've been banging my head for a while here any help appreciated.

Would ideally be promise/async.

Maybe I should look to find a XMLHttp request npm module?

```
var request_promise_native_options = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'http://requestbin.fullcontact.com/198flbs1',
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise',
            'Content-Type': 'text/xml'
            //'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(my_xml_string) //I've tried multiple ways to use this
        },
        body: {
            my_xml_string //also tried many ways here Buffer, String() etc
        },
        json: false // automatically stringifys body to json if true
    };

    request_promise(request_promise_native_options)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log("success");
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            })
```

Comment: `body: my_xml_string`

Comment: @KevinB thanks!! SO simply stupid and of course that works AND makes total sense now that I'm outside of my own perspective

Answer (score 5):

Kudos to @kevin-b to help me see the obvious. Simply remove {}

```
var request_promise_native_options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'http://requestbin.fullcontact.com/198flbs1',
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise',
        'Content-Type': 'text/xml'
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(my_xml_string)
    },
    body: my_xml_string,
    json: false // automatically stringifys body to json if true
};
```